# UICollectionView missing cells on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollectionView to display images from camera roll. And I've set up a UICollectionView, and subclassed a UICollectionViewCell in which has a UIImageView to hold the image.

And in the IB, I've set the height of the collection view to 88 and width to 320 which is full width of the screen, and the layout to "Flow" type, scrolling horizontally. The other properties like spacing, section insets are all set to 0.

Here's the strange part, the collection view works fine on my 4" iOS 7 device. But on my 3.5" iOS 6 device, it only shows 6 (out of 28) pictures, which means it picks the first one in every 5 images.

Here's my delegation part of the code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view 
                             numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_photoAssets count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView
                             :(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
```

And this is really weird, can anybody help me out?

*EDIT:* BTW, I'm using auto-layout, if that matters.

Comment: Did you check your _photoAssets that it contains 28 pictures right ?

Comment: @art, yeah, I NSLog() it, and it was 28.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved my question, seems I miss understood the section and numberOfItems in section. By switching the line:

```
return [_photoAssets count];
```

And

```
return 1;
```

I made it to show all images.